# EJB 3.0 how can I wrap an exception so that the client can handle it?

Tags: java, exception, glassfish, ejb

Got Ejb

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class UserManagerBean implements UserManagerBeanLocal {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Long registerUser(User user) throws UserAlreadyExistException {
        return userManagerDao.createUser(user);                     
    }
}
```

UserManagerDao catch database exception (or all Exceptions) and re throw it to UserManagerBean.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class UserAlreadyExistException extends Exception {

}
```

For some reason this exception is wrapped to EJBException and throw to client. That's what I see on client side.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted

javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted


javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.

root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

What I want to achieve is to catch application exception(UserAlreadyExistException) on the client side, but container wrap it and i can't

Just started to learn j2ee6. Using glassfish 3.0.  Am I missing something ?

**Update**

Sorry, i realized what was the problem, i was catching and re throwing exception on EntityManager.persist method in my dao-layer, which actually did not throw any exception, since persistence contexted was flushed on method end, not on persist invocation. This mean i did not even catch this exception

But actually it does not solve my problem, i don't understand where should i re throw exception, since both method are transactional.

Comment: Are you sure that userManagerDao is catching DatabaseException and re-throwing UserAlreadyExistException.  The error you posted points to a root cause of "org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call flush method of EntityManager during the transaction to catch DatabaseException and throw your own exception..

Comment: I accept your answer, it should work, i guess. But I'm not going to flush persistent context manually. Probably it is not best use-case to catch database exception.